# Jenkins can't launch scrtipt from tmp folder Permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, gitlab, devops

I'm learning jenkins and wanted to check freestyle job and got into problem.
I'm pulling repo from gitlab, then launching script freestyle-build.sh
Jenkins is running and installed through Docker.

```
[my-job] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins18109055234961560012.sh
+ chmod -R 777 freestyle-build.sh
+ whoami
jenkins
+ ls -l freestyle-build.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins 14 Jun  7 10:20 freestyle-build.sh
+ ./ freestyle-build.sh
/tmp/jenkins18109055234961560012.sh: 6: ./: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've tried changing permissions for script but got no result
`chmod -R 777 freestyle-build.sh`
Also tried restarting jenkins container but problem still remains.

Comment: The error is coming from the line 6 inside the `/tmp/jenkins18109055234961560012.sh`, could you please share it's content, otherwise it won't be possible to help.

Comment: What is in the `Jenkinsfile`?  Is this in the context of a `sh '...'` command?

Comment: @DavidMaze it's freestyle job, so I don't think there is Jenkinsfile. It just can't get to launch script from repo. And I don't know why it changes `freestyle-build.sh` to  `jenkins18109055234961560012.sh` 
I think thats why it cant get permission for executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are running Jenkins on docker pass a user flag in run command

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name my-jenkins --user root jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

And try again.